# How to remove rows in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, delete-row

I am faking a matrix as follows.

```
a = rep(1:4, each=2)
b = rep(0:1, times=4)
m = cbind(a, b)
m
a b
[1,] 1 0
[2,] 1 1
[3,] 2 0
[4,] 2 1
[5,] 3 0
[6,] 3 1
[7,] 4 0
[8,] 4 1
```

I need to remove any rows where `a==4` and `b==0`. I know how to select such rows:

```
m[m[,1]==4 & m[,2]==0,]
a b 
4 0
```

But I have no idea how to remove them. I know that I can do `m[-7,]` in this particular case. But image that this is a huge matrix and I cannot visually inspect which rows meet the condition as `a==4` and `b==0`. I also tried this:

```
count=1:8
m.count = cbind(m, count)
m.count[m.count[,1]==4 & m.count[,2]==0,]
a     b count 
4     0     7
```

So this will automatically tells me which rows meet the condition and then I can use the index `c=count[3]` (if only one row) or `c=count[,3]` (if more than one row) and try `m[-c,]` to get the right results.

But this solution is too lengthy. Does anyone know a easy way to solve the problem? I am expected to use `"-"` in some smart ways to do it.

Comment: Isn't `which` useful here or am I missing something? `m[-which(.), ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invert your condition for selecting rows:

```
m[! (m[, 1] == 4 & m[, 2] == 0), ]
```

Or indeed (as per [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
m[m[, 1] != 4 | m[, 2] != 0, ]
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad. It really helps. How come I couldn't see it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need `?which`

```
m <- m[-which(m[,1] == 4 & m[,2] == 0),]
```

Testing:

```
# Konrad's !

> system.time(rep(m[! (m[, 1] == 4 & m[, 2] == 0), ],10000000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.264   0.094   0.357 

# BB's which
> system.time(rep(m[-which(m[,1] == 4 & m[,2] == 0),],10000000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.244   0.109   0.354
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm actually not sure that it is...not to mention that it's easier to comprehend than typical negation.

Comment: You’re arguing that `-which(…)` is easier to comprehend than `!…`?

Comment: I find it easier to read than `!`. You may not. It's not an argument, it's a preference.

Comment: Regarding the benchmark, notice that what you’re benchmarking is mainly the performance of `rep`, not that of the operation: the operation is only executed *once* and then concatenated 10000000 times. The difference in performance is thus spurious. Using the `microbenchmark` package I found the following differences: https://gist.github.com/klmr/8718294 – In other words: on data frames, yours is faster; on matrices, mine. Or, equally as likely: it makes almost no difference.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to that package! Looks awesome.

Comment: `-which` is a no-no, see what happens in the event that there is no match. Try `x <- 1:3; x[-which(x < 0)]`. Always prefer the `!` form.

Comment: Interesting, that you see that as a bad thing. I see that as a good thing - it tells me that my condition wasn't matched...aka I made a mistake on the condition.

Comment: Come on... I give you a vector of positive numbers and ask you to remove all negative ones. Should you remove nothing or everything? `x[!(x < 0)]` is the only rational answer.

Comment: There aren't a lot of situations where I subset something and expect to get back everything. So knowing that my subset/condition failed is nice. By failed, I mean being unable to continue with further operations.

Comment: That happens more often than you think: remove NAs, remove outliers, etc. And it is not telling you a consistent story: see that if the vector had only negative numbers you would get the same output (an empty vector.). Robust code should not be sensitive to corner cases like these.

Comment: Definitely something to consider. Appreciate the discussion here @flodel